# Generic class inheritance

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

Is there a way to declare a generic class that extends from its parameter? I want to have a legal equivalent for what I'm trying to do here:

```
public class Box < T > extends  T{

}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Ok here's the context of my program. I'm designing a Class library for mathematical objects, there are classes to represent sums, products, complex and real numbers, etc. I'll like to have a container class called Constant in order to treat larger expresions as if they were complex numbers and use them as coeficients. The container class should have the same behavior as its content, so that is why I'm trying to do this.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do? Please explain it in more words, because your current code (and explanation) makes no sense, perhaps it is understandable after all once we know the details.

Take your example as example, with type parameter `T` := `Integer`.

Then you want to do the following:
`Box<Integer> extends Integer`

**Why** would you want that `Box<Integer>` is a subclass of `Integer`?
What do you gain with having that behaviour accomplished.

What you are asking is simply not possible in any (OOP) programming language and/or reasoning, and I do not see the need fo rit.

Comment: It is possible in C++. And is usable in certain cases.

Answer (score 1):

Generics are compile-time instrument, they do not exist at runtime. So the direct answer to your question is "no".